# Difference between operator.truth and bool

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python, `operator.truth` and `bool` can both convert an object to a boolean value.

What's the difference? When should I use each of them?

Comment: On even days the one, on odd days the other. It doesn't matter according to [their description](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html).

Comment: [*"This is equivalent to using the `bool` constructor."*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.truth) (Although it doesn't [actually](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/operator.py#L57) *use* it.) So just pick one.

Comment: @johnrsharpe: that’s the pure Python backstop. The C implementation uses the very same function the `bool` type uses to convert arguments to a Boolean value.

Comment: There is very little *opinion based* material in this question, so I reopened it. If people take issue with the *when should I use each* part, feel free to reword it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for `operator.truth()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.truth) is quite clear:

> This is equivalent to using the `bool` constructor.

So there is *no difference*. The only reason that `operator.truth` exists is for the module to be complete.

Use it when it is more convenient for your code than `bool`; for example, when your code already switches between various `operator` callables dynamically (say, based on a string mapping).

Answer (score 0):

From the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.truth):

> **operator.truth(obj)**
>
> Return True if obj is true, and False otherwise. This is equivalent to using the bool constructor.

So both operations are equivalent.